# How to view database tables in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I created an Asp.net-core-mvc project, defined DBContext and added migrations. How can I view tables created in my project's database using SSMS?
If possible, provide the method step by step.

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL Server Management" and "Microsoft SQL Management"? Do you mean SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

Comment: Yes. SSMS. SQL server management studio.

Comment: With the greatest of respect, once you've connected to the instance with SSMS, it should be *very* obvious how to see what tables are in your database; have you tried? Where did you get confused?

Comment: I can not see my project database. Should I connect to my database? How cant to do this?

Comment: What do you mean you "can't see it"? As in, no user databases are listed in the object explorer? Have you connected to the right instance? Has the `LOGIN` you used been denied the `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission? If so, connect to the database you need directly, rather than the default database for your `LOGIN` (probably `master`).

Comment: There was a slight problem with the connecting string. By modifying it, the databases were created and viewable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the tree to get to your table, then right-click, select 'Select Top 1000 Rows'

[image]